# Scraped data printed in a repetitive manner

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Writing a script in python using selenium, when I run it I get scraped data in weirdly repetitive format. I expected to parse the first table from a webpage which is mentioned in my script.

Here is the script I've tried so far with to parse the first table:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/")

table_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='ism-table']")[0]

list_rows = []

for items in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):

    list_cells = []

    for item in items.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td"):

        list_cells.append(item.text)

    list_rows.append(list_cells)

    print(list_rows)

driver.quit()
```

The result I'm getting can be seen if you follow the link:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4n08jt2k7amx4j/Parsed%20table%20data.txt?dl=0"

Html elements, within which data are stored:

```
<table class="ism-table">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="ismCol1">
            <col class="ismCol2">
            <col class="ismCol3">
            <col class="ismCol4">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Player</th>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Courtois</td>
                <td>Chelsea</td>
                <td>141</td>
                <td>£5.9</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not drop value of `list_cells` after each internal loop:

```
list_rows = []

for items in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):

    list_cells = []

    for item in items.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td"):

        list_cells.append(item.text)

    list_rows.append(list_cells)
    list_cells=[]

print(list_rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, it definitely works. Basically, I got the idea from you what I was after. My pasted code was flawed with indentation. Thanks again. I'm gonna paste my updated code to show what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I was expecting:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/")

table_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='ism-table']")[0]

list_rows = []

for items in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):

    list_cells = []

    for item in items.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td"):

        list_cells.append(item.text)

    list_rows.append(list_cells)

for data in list_rows:

    print(data)

driver.quit()
```